# Nested json unmarshaling with 2d slices into struct not working in golang

Tags: json, multidimensional-array, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have a json structure that looks like

```
{
"devices": [
    {
        "server": {
            "bu": {
                "add_info": false,
                "applications": [
                    [
                        "Systems",
                        12
                    ],
                    [
                        "SomeProject",
                        106
                    ]
                ],
                "name": [
                    [
                        "SomeName",
                        4
                    ],
                    [
                        "CommonName",
                        57
                    ]
                ],
                "owners": [
                    "SomeOwner1",
                    "SomeOwner2"
                ],
                "users": [
                    "SomeUser1",
                    "SomeUser2"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to add it to a struct, and the struct looks like

```
type TwoD [][]string
type MainContainer struct {
    Devices []struct{
        Server struct{
            Bu struct{
                Add_info string `json:"add_info"`
                Applications TwoD `json:"applications"`
                Name TwoD `json:"name"`
                Owners []string `json:"owners"`
                Users []string `json:"users"`
               } `json:"bu"`
               } `json:"server"`
    } `json:"devices"`
}
```

However, when I am printing the struct, I get only one value from the 2D slice and nothing beyond it.

```
func main() {
jsonfile, err  := ioutil.ReadFile("./search.json")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
var jsonobject MainContainer
json.Unmarshal(jsonfile, &jsonobject)
fmt.Printf("%v", jsonobject)
}
```

`{[{{{ [[Systems ]] [] [] []}}}]}`

But if I am omitting the 2d slices in the struct like

```
type MainContainer struct {
Devices []struct{
        Server struct{
            Bu struct{
                Add_info string `json:"add_info"`
                //Applications TwoD `json:"applications"`
                //Name TwoD `json:"name"`
                Owners []string `json:"owners"`
                Users []string `json:"users"`
               } `json:"bu"`
               } `json:"server"`
    } `json:"devices"`
}
```

everything is printed as

`{[{{{ [SomeOwner1 SomeOwner2] [SomeUser1 SomeUser2]}}}]}`

Could someone help me identify what is wrong here?

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/RgGmYyo-AY) is the link to the golang playground with the struct and sample json. The two TwoD slices are commented in the struct there.

Note:: Edited the playground link with one 2d slice uncommented so that the difference can be noted, and changed the type string to bool, as pointed out by [@cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar), Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you're not handling the error returned by `json.Unmarshal`. Once you handle that, problems with your json (and the decoding struct) become obvious.

```
if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonfile, &jsonobject); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Unmarshal: %v\n", err)
}
```

First:

> Unmarshal json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go value of type string

So `Add_info` should be `bool`. After fixing that and uncommenting `Applications`:

> Unmarshal json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string

After changing 12 to "12" and 106 to "106" the result is:

```
{[{{{false [[Systems 12] [SomeProject 106]] [SomeUser1 SomeUser2]}}}]}
```

Comment: Thank you @cnicutar. I missed that. However, when I changed it to bool, it still stops at the multidimensional array. https://play.golang.org/p/2HMUi6JadG
I have uncommented the 2d slice part in the struct and you can see the difference.

Comment: Ah never mind, your error catching helped me. It is a slice of string and a number, so I put an empty interface

Comment: @nohuo stop go development, [read this](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), then continue your go development.

Comment: Thank you @eduncan911, started it.